# Low level nested field is preferred than top level nested field in the Mongodb Projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the below data inserted in the "testProjection" collection.

```
{
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed",
    "command" : {
        "name" : "Run",
        "strike" : 15,
        "score" : true,
        "duration" : 123
    }
},
{
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed",
    "command" : {
        "name" : "Run",
        "strike" : 12,
        "score" : false,
        "duration" : 597
    }
}
```

My Query is:

```
db.testProjection.find({},{"command":0,"command.score":0})
```

## Actaul result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599d27944be6e513549dd170"),
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed",
    "command" : {
        "name" : "Run",
        "strike" : 15.0,
        "duration" : 123.0
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599d27944be6e513549dd171"),
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed",
    "command" : {
        "name" : "Run",
        "strike" : 12.0,
        "duration" : 597.0
    }
}
```

## Expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599d27944be6e513549dd170"),
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599d27944be6e513549dd171"),
    "eventname" : "Ball Passed"
}
```

In the mongodb projection, the query engine in the Mongodb is prefering nested low level projection instead top level projection.

Is this desired behaviour in mongodb? Is there any way to achieve my expected out using mongodb query?

Comment: You can also check result of `db.testProjection.find({},{"command.score":0, "command":0})` ;).

Comment: Yes it is desired behavior and expected. Moreover if you specified the other way around `db.testProjection.find({},{ "command.score": 0, "command": 0 })` then the sub-property is removed and the subsequent exclusion removes even the other properties, leaving you with `command: {}`. So the intent is generally to "stack" the paths, as in `db.testProjection.find({},{ "command.score": 0, "command.duration": 0 })` and if you really intended to remove "everything", then you would issue only that. But its actually "order precedence" as opposed to "depth precedence".

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to achieve my expected out using MongoDb query?

You can *include* your expected fields instead of *exclude*ing fields like:

```
db.testProjection.find(
    {},
    {
        _id: 1,
        eventname: 1
    }
);
```

---

But I think it's better to use an aggregate like this - As a performance issue - :

```
db.testProjection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id : 1,
                eventname: 1
            }
        },
    ]
);
```